# If a QNaN and SNaN is applied as an input to a floating point move instruction (FMV.X.S), what could be the possible output and exceptions

Tags: riscv

If a QNaN and SNaN is applied as an input to a floating point move instruction (FMV.X.S), what could be the possible output and exceptions for a RISC-V 32-bit implementation

Comment: You should read up on the "IEEE-754" 2008 standard, or at least add that tag to your question to get a broader range of responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FMV never raises an exception.

FCVT.{W|L}[U].{S|D} raise the invalid exception whenever the floating-point value cannot be represented in the integer format.  This includes out-of-range values, infinities, and NaNs.  Whether the NaN is signaling makes no difference in this case.

In general, the RISC-V FP instructions conform to the exception behavior of the corresponding operations in the IEEE 754-2008 standard.